# Meaning of このなかでは

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

I keep on hearing the term 「このなかでは」 and 「そのなかでは」from news, but I can't seem to find what it means anywhere. I found a meaning for 中, which is probably what なか refers to, as "while". Does it mean "meanwhile"?

Answer (score 3):

- 中: "inside", "middle", etc.
- この中: "inside of this"
- で: place marker
- は: topic marker

この中では/その中では is used in two ways:

1. Literally, "Inside this/that"

   > ここが我々の工場です。**この中では**缶詰が作られています。
2. As an established set phrase, "Among these/those"

   > アメリカには50の州があります。**この中では**アラスカの面積が最大です。

Answer (score 1):

According to WWWJDIC, この中で　is "amoung these", and the "は" is most likely the topic marker.  I would not define 中 as while at all (as in 箱の中に "inside the box")...  So literally, I read it as "this (thing) within as for".